# How can I change some parts in a text file after a specified word?

Tags: html, c++-cli

I'm trying to make a web-browser editor program. My idea was, to make a txt file, which will functionate as a sample to an HTML file. The program will edit some parts of the txt, based on what the user of the program chose (for example photos, text etc.), and make an html file of it.

To make it possible, I should be able to add text to a text file, after a specified word, or change parts of the file.

For example if I want to add a text, like an article, to the template file, I should find the phrase

and then add the text after it.

My question is, that how could I do this in C++/Cli?

here is what I've got now:
(it merges two template txt files with the text the user wrote into a textbox)

```
`StreamReader ^sr1;
StreamReader ^sr2;

String^template1 = "template1.html";
sr1 = File::OpenText(template1);
String^template2 = "template2.html";
sr2 = File::OpenText(template2);

if (saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
String^fn;
fn = saveFileDialog1->FileName;
String^szov;

StreamWriter ^ sw;
sw = File::CreateText(fn);
while (!sr1->EndOfStream)
{
    szov = sr1->ReadLine();
    sw->WriteLine(szov);
}

array<String^>^ lines = letrehoz_szovegmezo->Lines;
int count = lines->Length;
for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
{
    sw->WriteLine(lines[idx]);
    sw->Write("</br></br>");
}

while (!sr2->EndOfStream)
{
    szov = sr2->ReadLine();
    sw->WriteLine(szov);
}

sw->Close();
sr1->Close();
sr2->Close();`
```

Comment: I can't see any question to answer. Only I can say: Yes you can do it in C++/CLI. And your code will do what you describe without deeply testing it. So make your question more precise.